# map.yaml format

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to create map in yaml format ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42782/map.yaml-format/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [map_name].yaml file only contains metadata about the map, which is given as a separate [map_name].pgm image file. You can create maps by using a SLAM algorithm and saving it using the map_saver tool. In principle, you can also edit maps by editing .pgm files with a graphics editing program of your choice.

Most relevant information can be found on the [map_server](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server) wiki page.

How to generate maps with SLAM algorithms is described [here (gmapping)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) and [here (hector_mapping)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-15**:
So I can use GIMP to make a map even? If I then go on to write the meta-data (.yaml) file myself?
What colors should I use for the map?
Thank you.